# Testing MinMax with alpha-beta pruning and strategy for play

Tags: algorithm, testing, artificial-intelligence

I have made game (Connect-4) and used MinMax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning for computer AI. What is good way to test correctness of my alpha-beta ? I am not sure of correctness, sometimes when playing against my AI it doesnt make the play that will make the game last longer if it has seen a loss deeper down and it is difficult to check things by hand and with unit testing when it starts searching just litle deep (7-9 moves). How can one fix this ? (I know if alpha beta might prune something that give more difficult win if there is no way not to lose)

Comment: Is this a Floyed-Warshall algorithm?

Comment: No. Floyd is with weighted graphs finding cheapest path. Maybe possible to transform problem to Floyd but this is standard MinMax with alfa-beta [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Connect-4 (as a program). Do you search to deterministic values (win/loose/draw) or do you have a heuristic (evaluation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well alpha-beta pruning is only an optimization for the basic MiniMax algorithm (i.e. exclude paths that certainly won't be taken by an optimal playing enemy), so I'd just compare the results of the alpha-beta algorithm to the simpler MiniMax one. As soon as they disagree you've got a bug in one of the two algorithms.

That simplifies the problem to testing wether your MiniMax algorithm is correct and well I can't think of any special tricks for that - but since it's a recursive function it should be possible to write Unittests for all cases

Comment: Then one has to choose some sort of ordering on moves besides their values to make such comparison between MiniMax and Alfa-Beta, as else Alfa-Beta might prune the move MiniMax chooses. Also in practice even with simple game like connect-4 I have to use cutoff function so I don't see how this testing works as its not possible to search to bottom of game tree with Minimax because of the number of nodes in tree.

Comment: A MiniMax with AlphaBeta should find a variant with the same _score_ as a search without pruning, but not necessarily the same chain of moves. This is a basis for testing but I think you will need quite a few (hand-picked) test-cases to get some confidence.

Comment: As long as you use the same heuristic for both algorithms it won't influence the result. And yes, you may only land at a node with the same score - although I think as long as you visit the nodes in the same order and let minimax always choose the first path (i.e. the one alpha beta would find first too) I think you should land at the same node (well on first glance I think it's a valid assumption, but there could be edge cases). And since Alpha-beta is only an extended minimax it would be surprising if the order of moves were changed anyhow.

Comment: Ok I am gonna close this one and accept that there is no "standard way" to do this without quite a bit of human interaction.